# Reading properties from config file with Flask and Python

Tags: python, flask

Building from [Reading config file as dictionary in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415433/reading-config-file-as-dictionary-in-flask) I'm attempting to define a custom configuration file in order to customize my Flask app.

Running code :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import os

my_config = app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join('.', 'config/app.conf'), silent=False)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    with app.open_instance_resource('app.cfg') as f:
        print(type(f.read()))

    return 'Hello World! {}'.format(app.config.get('LOGGING'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In config/app.conf these properties are added :

```
myvar1="tester"
myvar2="tester"
myvar3="tester"
```

Invoking the service for `hello_world()` function returns :

```
Hello World! None
```

Shouldn't the contents of the file be returned instead of None ?

I attempt to access a property using `app.config.get('myvar1')` but `None` is also returned in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [official Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#configuring-from-files):

> The configuration files themselves are actual Python files. Only values in uppercase are actually stored in the config object later on. **So make sure to use uppercase letters for your config keys.**

Therefore, set structure your `./config/app.conf` variables as:

```
VARIABLE_NAME = "variable value"
```

Load as:

```
app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join(".", "config/app.conf"), silent=False)
```

NOTE: If you're not using instance specific configuration you don't actually need to *build* the path as it will take the Flask app path as its root.

And access the values later as:

```
app.config.get("VARIABLE_NAME")
```

Comment: Hi @zwer, if there are backslashes in the value set, then they double when retrieved. Can you help in resolving this issue? I have raised a new thread for this at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991045/why-is-flask-config-value-automatically-doubling-backslashes-when-retrieved